# using .wrapInner instead of .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

newbie here. I am trying to used jquery wrapInner to show the next choice for the user while trying to hide the original element. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesliam/4NdUX/1/).

Once I click endorse radio button it hide the elements in between . The cancel button show the elements back. But clicking endorse radio button again nothing happen.

Any help on this would be more than appreciated !

html:

```
<div id="engr-action" >
  <div id="engr-choice">
    <input id="endorse" class="engr-choice" type="radio" name="encoder-pick"/>
      <label for="endorse">ENDORSEMENT</label>
    <input id="encode" class="engr-choice" type="radio" name="encoder-pick"/>
      <label for="encode">ENCODE</label>      
  </div>
  <button id="cancel-action">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
$('#engr-choice').buttonset();

$('#cancel-action')
  .button()
  .click(function() { 
    $('#engr-choice').html('');
    $('#endorse-edit').hide();

    $('#engr-choice').wrapInner('<input id="endorse" class="engr-choice" type="radio" name="encoder-pick"/><label for="endorse">ENDORSEMENT</label>');                

    $('#engr-choice input').removeAttr('checked');       
    $('#engr-choice').buttonset('refresh');       

    return false;
  });

$('#endorse').click(function(){     
    $('#engr-choice').html('');
    $('#engr-choice').wrapInner('<div id="endorse-edit"><a href="">Edit</a></div>');
    $('#endorse-edit').button();        

    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if .wrapInner is a good choice here. Your trying to reconstruct the DOM everytime a button is clicked which can quickly lead to messy code.

Can you explain what you're trying to do in better details?

Comment: This part of the html code is under a table column name action where table consist of a checkbox column, control no. column, task column, and this one action column. The action column consist of other html similar to this. Every row of the table is affected by a progress status lets say 1 to 10. The engr-choice is shown on a specific progress status like 1,3,5,6. Both answers below are correct. They both explain the answer in someway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your element is generated "on the fly", thru javascript, your `$('#endorse').click(..` event wont work as that element did not exist on DOM, so in order to add events to your elements, created on the fly, you would need to use event delegation, so
change:

```
$('#endorse').click(function(){     
..
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#endorse',function(){
...
```

See:: [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NdUX/4/)

Comment: @jcsanyi as your elements are created on the fly, from js script and NOT loaded on page load, you need to delegate event to such elements..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [**Fiddle setup**](http://jsfiddle.net/4NdUX/5/)

```
$(function () {
$('#engr-choice').buttonset();

$('#cancel-action').button().click(function () {
      $('#engr-choice').html('');
      $('#endorse-edit').hide();
      $('#engr-choice').append('<input id="endorse" class="engr-choice" type="radio" name="encoder-pick"/>        <label for="endorse">ENDORSEMENT</label>');
      $('#engr-choice input').prop('checked', false);
      return false;
   });

   $('#engr-action').on('click', '#endorse', function () {
      $('#engr-choice').html('');
      $('#engr-choice').wrapInner('<div id="endorse-edit"><a href="">Edit</a></div>');
      $('#endorse-edit').button();
   });
});
```

As you are putting html elements via javascript/jQuery so direct binding of events won't be available for them, so you need to do it via `event delegation` that is to delegate the event to the static closest parent which is in your case is `#engr-action` or you can do it with `$(document)` which is always available to delegate the events.